# How to check if element has a class

Tags: jquery

I have this line of HTML:

```
<li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 filter active" data-filter=".office">
```

And i want to check if the 
`".filter"` has class `".active"`, if it has active class then i need to get its data attribute.
I tried like this, but it alerts undefined

```
if($(".filter").hasClass("active")) {

    var activeFilter = $(this).attr("data-filter");
    alert(activeFilter);
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Where `this` not refers to the element which may refer to `window` object or any other context. To make it work, cache the element reference(jQuery object) and do the rest on the cached object.

```
var $ele = $(".filter");
if($ele.hasClass("active")) {
    var activeFilter = $ele.attr("data-filter");
    alert(activeFilter);
}
```

```js
var $ele = $(".filter");
if ($ele.hasClass("active")) {
  var activeFilter = $ele.attr("data-filter");
  alert(activeFilter);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 filter active" data-filter=".office"></li>
</ul>
```

---

Or in case there are multiple elements then use [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method and you can refer the current element using this keyword within the callback.

```
$(".filter").each(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    var activeFilter = $(this).attr("data-filter");
    alert(activeFilter);
  }
})
```

```js
$(".filter").each(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    var activeFilter = $(this).attr("data-filter");
    alert(activeFilter);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 filter active" data-filter=".office"></li>
</ul>
```